# Match all combinations of list with other list

Tags: python

I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3']
```

And I want to create a dictionary with all possible combinations of list2 with list1, something like:

```
output= [{'A':'1', 'B':'1', 'C':'1'},{'A':'2', 'B':'1', 'C':1'} ..., {'A':'3', 'B':'3', 'C':'3'}]
```

I tried:

```
combinations = ([dict(zip(list1,v)) for v in product(list2)])
```

But isn't what I expected

Comment: Are you perhaps after `product(list2, repeat=3)` untested but should give you what I think you're expecting ?

Answer (score 7):

```
import itertools

list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3']
output = []
for p in itertools.product(list2, repeat=len(list1)):  # (1,1,1),(1,1,2),...,(3,3,3)
    # print (dict(zip(list1, p)))
    output.append(dict(zip(list1, p)))

print (output)

# One line
output = [dict(zip(list1, p)) for p in itertools.product(list2, repeat=len(list1))]
```

`itertools.product` returns all possible value-"pairs" you want, with the argument `repeat` denoting the length of each permutation(with repetition?)

Comment: I added a one-liner :)

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `itertools.product`.
- The following solution is scalable for any `list1` and `list2` size.

```
from itertools import product

list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3']

pro = list(product(list2, repeat=len(list1)))

combinations = [dict(zip(list1, p)) for p in pro ]

print(ombinations)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that the keys in the dictionaries will always be the same, you could try something like this:

```
list_of_dicts = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(1, 4):
        for k in range(1, 4):
            list_of_dicts.append({'A':str(i), 'B':str(j), 'C':str(k)})
```

Comment: Imagine when there're more than 3 variables hmm (In fact that's how I learned about `itertools` - when I didn't want to type 20 for loops hahaha)

Comment: True, this isn't a scalable solution. Your solution takes care of that issue. Well done :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursion for a no-import solution:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3']
def combos(d, c = []):
  if len(c) < len(d):
     yield from [i for b in d for i in combos(d, c+[b])]
  else:
     yield dict(zip(list1, c))

print(list(combos(list2)))
```

Output:

```
[{'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '1', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '1', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '1', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '1', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '1', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '1', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '2', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '2', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '3', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '3', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '3', 'C': '3'}]
```